# What was the Airfoil of Handley Page P.115?

Tags: aircraft-design, aerodynamics, airfoil

This extreme sweptback delta was built to test the Concorde wing at low speeds, sources say it had a biconv 6% airfoil, but I failed in finding data about it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you see what Wikipedia had for it, and the book it came from?

> Specifications (HP.115)
>   Data from X-Planes and Prototypes: From Nazi Secret Weapons to the Warplanes of the Future [Winchester 2005, p. 134]
>
> General characteristics
>
> Crew: one
>
> Length: 50 ft 4 in (15.33 m)
>
> Wingspan: 20 ft (6.1 m)
>
> Height: 12 ft 9 in (3.9 m)
>
> Wing area: 432 ft² (40.1 m²)
>
> Airfoil: Bicon 6%
>
> Empty weight: 3,680 lb (1,670 kg)
>
> Useful load: (Fuel) 1,175 lb (533 kg)
>
> Loaded weight: 5,050 lb (2,291 kg)
>
> Powerplant: 1 × Bristol Siddeley Viper BSV.9 turbojet, 1,900 lbf static (8.455 kN)
>   Performance
>
> Maximum speed: 248 mph (399 km/h)
>
> Endurance: 40 minutes

This paper goes into calculations on biconvex airfoil as well, interesting reading  https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19930085007.pdf

Comment: Thanks for the good NACA 252 paper, but even with this info, I'm not able yet of drawing a: 'Bicon 6%' airfoil.

Comment: Time to check the libraries in your area and see if any have the book: Data from X-Planes and Prototypes: From Nazi Secret Weapons to the Warplanes of the Future [Winchester 2005, p. 134]

Comment: To CrossRoads: the excellent book: 'X-planes and prototypes' just arrived. No mention of an airfoil in the two pages about Handley Page HP.115. I insist: this HP.115 is almost identical to the Roy Scroggs': 'Flying Dart', The last laugh!', Pat US3051415,1932, including many interesting features, as a low dorsal fin, matching XXI century Chinese research (Xuanshi Meng et al), extended elevons ('Tailess Aircraft', K Nickel&M Wohlfahrt),...